# how to tell laravel to automatically decode urls

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How do I tell laravel to automatically turn this

http://laraone.oo/backend/activate/8%3Fexpires%3D1530213677

into this

http://laraone.oo/backend/activate/8?expires=1530213677

I am currently getting the first type of link when I submit something via post method from the vue, and if I remember correctly there is somewhere in laravel a place where I can enable laravel to convert all first type of links into second type of links before the rest of app boots up and starts processing the url's.

Comment: I think this is a front-end issue, seems like you'd want to handle it by fixing your requests to go to the correct URLs.

Comment: I am making a post from the javascript application and for some reason even thought I make a post with second type of urls, server recieves them as first type of urls and then nothing works correctly

Answer (score 0):

Use `urldecode`

```
echo urldecode("http://laraone.oo/backend/activate/8%3Fexpires%3D1530213677");
```

Will return http://laraone.oo/backend/activate/8?expires=1530213677

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php